# Ubuntu won't boot after installing on MacBook Pro 6,2?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, macbook, refind

I installed Ubuntu Trusty Tahr(14.04) on my MacBook Pro 6,2. But, after installing all the updates, and restarting, I can't boot anymore.

I installed [The rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html), on my MacBook. At boot up, I selected the Ubuntu Partition, and pressed <kbd>esc</kbd>, and <kbd>e</kbd> to start editing `grub`, after that, I added `nomodeset`, and a Q/A on Ask Ubuntu suggested to add `nomodset` instead of `nomodeset`? But, still not working. I get greeted with a blank - black - screen.

I booted on the recovery kernel, enabled networking, executed `apt-get update`, `update-grub`, and installed the `nvidia-settings` packages, as I read online that, that could also be a problem? But, again, black screen.

Google and DuckDuckGo couldn't help me find a solution, I'm hoping you guys can!

Comment: It sounds from your description as if you *can* boot, but video isn't working. If so, that's likely a problem with your video driver, not a boot loader issue per se (although a kernel option passed via your boot loader might help). I'm less versed on video problems than on boot problems, so the main point of this comment is that your subject and tags may be wrong to attract the attention you need.

Comment: @RodSmith thank you for the comment. I passed some boot arguments, and found out that it probably is a compatibility issues withe the MacBook Pro, which has And Intel graphic card, and nvidia graphics cards. Yep it has two graphics card. So, probably more issues than the bootloader. This is not worth the time, for now, I'm leaving this